# New serpentine belt makes noise and lifts

Tags: chevrolet, serpentine-belt, k1500

1994 Chevy K1500 4x4 - So I changed my serpentine belt but when I start it it has a clicking sound. when I look in the engine bay the belt on the harmonic balancer is lifting up on the side how can I fix that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you better explain what *lifting up* means? And which side of the balancer (as you are look at it from the front of the vehicle)?

Comment: Put a new belt tensioner on it.